# Creating panoramic 360 web with react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, web, three.js, virtual-reality, react-three-fiber

I'm working on a website and love the idea of integrating Three.js and React, but can't find how to do some actions. Read about the VR implementation, but can't get the panoramic view like [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-smoke-z3gtf?file=/src/index.js)(sometime you need to refresh for it to work).

It uses WebGLRenderer, PerspectiveCamera and OrbitControls. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `three.js` provides a panorama VR example: https://threejs.org/examples/webxr_vr_panorama. Maybe it's a useful code template for you.

Comment: Looks great! But it's using WebVR, which is not widely supported. Just found an example, will see how I can use if to form an answer. :)

Comment: @FrancoPetra Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Yes, I did! Can't find the gist I used to make it work but here's the repo. 
https://github.com/francopetra/grawlab
Not the cleanest code but I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a quick-and-easy panoramic video player:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { BackSide } from 'three'

interface Props{
  src: string
  size?: number
}

const VideoSphere = ({ src, size = 500 }: Props) => {
  const [video] = useState(() => {
    const el = document.createElement('video')
    el.src = src
    el.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
    el.play()
    return el
  })
  return <mesh scale={[-size, size, size]}>
    <sphereGeometry/>
    <meshBasicMaterial side={BackSide}>
      <videoTexture attach="map" args={[video]}/>
    </meshBasicMaterial>
  </mesh>
}
```

This component has three important steps:

1. Scale the mesh to be big, but less than 1000 to remain in frustum
2. Set material to show backside triangles
3. Invert x axis to avoid mirror image